# I need to add a custom form size to the local Print Server through code

Tags: c#, winapi, printing, batch-file

I need to add a custom form size to the local Print Server through code. I would like to do it in a `bat` file or in `C#`, or possibly in something else I can run when running my InstallShield installer.

To better explain, to do this manually, open Devices and Printers and click on a printer. Then click Print Server Properties. The form below will open, and you can view/add/delete Forms. I would like to add a new one here through code (then eventually select this new paper size in the printers Advanced options).

[image]

Comment: [Adding custom paper sizes to named printers](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12229/Adding-custom-paper-sizes-to-named-printers)

Comment: @RobertHarvey Your link worked perfectly. Do you want to post it as an answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This code project article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12229/Adding-custom-paper-sizes-to-named-printers) explains how to do it, and presumably has some helper classes and methods.  Some sample code is below:

```
var formInfo = new FormInfo1();
formInfo.Flags = 0;
formInfo.pName = paperName;
// all sizes in 1000ths of millimeters
formInfo.Size.width = (int)(widthMm * 1000.0); 
formInfo.Size.height = (int)(heightMm * 1000.0);
formInfo.ImageableArea.left = 0;
formInfo.ImageableArea.right = formInfo.Size.width;
formInfo.ImageableArea.top = 0;
formInfo.ImageableArea.bottom = formInfo.Size.height;

// Add the paper size to the printer's list of available paper sizes:
bool bFormAdded = AddForm(hPrinter, 1, ref formInfo);
```

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12229/Adding-custom-paper-sizes-to-named-printers

Answer (score 2):

I get code from here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12229/Adding-custom-paper-sizes-to-named-printers. But it dosnt work.

1. You need to replace **FormInfo1** from source code to this --v--v--v--

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
internal struct FormInfo1
{
    public uint Flags;
    public String pName;
    public structSize Size;
    public structRect ImageableArea;
};
```

2. And dont use this method **"AddCustomPaperSize"** - it dosn't work

Only method **"AddCustomPaperSizeToDefaultPrinter"** is working (for me)

Here is result:
[image]

Here is full work code:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing.Printing;

namespace MJMCustomPrintForm
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Summary description for MJMCustomPrintForm.
  /// </summary>
  public class MJMCustomPrintForm
  {
    // Make a static class
    private MJMCustomPrintForm()
    {
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
      internal struct structPrinterDefaults
    {
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] public String pDatatype;
      public IntPtr pDevMode;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)] public int DesiredAccess;
    };

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint="OpenPrinter", SetLastError=true,
       CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling=false,CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall),
    SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurityAttribute()]
    internal static extern bool OpenPrinter([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
      string printerName,
      out IntPtr phPrinter,
      ref structPrinterDefaults pd);
  
    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint="ClosePrinter", SetLastError=true,
       CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling=false,
       CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall),SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurityAttribute()]
    internal static extern bool ClosePrinter(IntPtr phPrinter);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
      internal struct structSize
    {
      public Int32 width;
      public Int32 height;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
      internal struct structRect
    {
      public Int32 left;
      public Int32 top;
      public Int32 right;
      public Int32 bottom;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    internal struct FormInfo1
    {
      public uint Flags;
      public String pName;
      public structSize Size;
      public structRect ImageableArea;
    };
    //[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    //internal struct FormInfo1
    //{
    //  [FieldOffset(0), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)] public uint Flags;
    //  [FieldOffset(4), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] public String pName;
    //  [FieldOffset(8)] public structSize Size;
    //  [FieldOffset(16)] public structRect ImageableArea;
    //};

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi/* changed from CharSet=CharSet.Auto */)]
      internal struct structDevMode
    {
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=32)] public String
        dmDeviceName;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)] public short dmSpecVersion;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)] public short dmDriverVersion;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)] public short dmSize;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)] public short dmDriverExtra;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] public int dmFields;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I2)] public short dmOrientation;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I2)] public short dmPaperSize;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I2)] public short dmPaperLength;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I2)] public short dmPaperWidth;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I2)] public short dmScale;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I2)] public short dmCopies;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I2)] public short dmDefaultSource;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I2)] public short dmPrintQuality;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I2)] public short dmColor;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I2)] public short dmDuplex;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I2)] public short dmYResolution;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I2)] public short dmTTOption;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I2)] public short dmCollate;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=32)] public String dmFormName;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)] public short dmLogPixels;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] public int dmBitsPerPel;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] public int dmPelsWidth;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] public int dmPelsHeight;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] public int dmNup;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] public int dmDisplayFrequency;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] public int dmICMMethod;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] public int dmICMIntent;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] public int dmMediaType;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] public int dmDitherType;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] public int dmReserved1;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] public int dmReserved2;
    }

      [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Auto)] 
         internal struct PRINTER_INFO_9 
      {
         public IntPtr pDevMode;
      }

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint="AddFormW", SetLastError=true,
       CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling=true,
       CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurityAttribute()]
    internal static extern bool AddForm(
         IntPtr phPrinter,
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)] int level, 
         ref FormInfo1 form);


    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint="DeleteForm", SetLastError=true,
       CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling=false,CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall),
    SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurityAttribute()]
    internal static extern bool DeleteForm(
         IntPtr phPrinter,
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string pName);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint="GetLastError", SetLastError=false,
       ExactSpelling=true, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall),
    SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurityAttribute()]
    internal static extern Int32 GetLastError();

    [DllImport("GDI32.dll", EntryPoint="CreateDC", SetLastError=true,
       CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling=false,
       CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall),
    SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurityAttribute()]
    internal static extern IntPtr CreateDC([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
      string pDrive,
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string pName,
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string pOutput,
      ref structDevMode pDevMode);

    [DllImport("GDI32.dll", EntryPoint="ResetDC", SetLastError=true,
       CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling=false,
       CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall),
    SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurityAttribute()]
    internal static extern IntPtr ResetDC(
         IntPtr hDC, 
         ref structDevMode
      pDevMode);

    [DllImport("GDI32.dll", EntryPoint="DeleteDC", SetLastError=true,
       CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling=false,
       CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall),
    SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurityAttribute()]
    internal static extern bool DeleteDC(IntPtr hDC);

      [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint="SetPrinterA", SetLastError=true,
          CharSet=CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling=true,
          CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurityAttribute()]
      internal static extern bool SetPrinter(
         IntPtr hPrinter,
         [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)] int level, 
         IntPtr pPrinter, 
         [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)] int command);

      /*
       LONG DocumentProperties(
         HWND hWnd,               // handle to parent window 
         HANDLE hPrinter,         // handle to printer object
         LPTSTR pDeviceName,      // device name
         PDEVMODE pDevModeOutput, // modified device mode
         PDEVMODE pDevModeInput,  // original device mode
         DWORD fMode              // mode options
         );
       */
      [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint="DocumentPropertiesA", SetLastError=true, 
      ExactSpelling=true, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)] 
      public static extern int DocumentProperties(
         IntPtr hwnd, 
         IntPtr hPrinter,
         [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string pDeviceName /* changed from String to string */,
         IntPtr pDevModeOutput, 
         IntPtr pDevModeInput, 
         int fMode
         );

      [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint="GetPrinterA", SetLastError=true, 
      ExactSpelling=true, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)] 
      public static extern bool GetPrinter(
         IntPtr hPrinter, 
         int dwLevel /* changed type from Int32 */,
         IntPtr pPrinter,
         int dwBuf /* chagned from Int32*/, 
         out int dwNeeded /* changed from Int32*/
         ); 

      // SendMessageTimeout tools
      [Flags] public enum SendMessageTimeoutFlags : uint
      {
         SMTO_NORMAL         = 0x0000,
         SMTO_BLOCK          = 0x0001,
         SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG    = 0x0002,
         SMTO_NOTIMEOUTIFNOTHUNG = 0x0008
      }
      const int WM_SETTINGCHANGE = 0x001A;
      const int HWND_BROADCAST = 0xffff;

      [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
      public static extern IntPtr SendMessageTimeout(
         IntPtr windowHandle, 
         uint Msg, 
         IntPtr wParam, 
         IntPtr lParam, 
         SendMessageTimeoutFlags flags, 
         uint timeout, 
         out IntPtr result
         );
      
      public static void AddMjm80MmPaperSizeToDefaultPrinter()
      {
         AddCustomPaperSizeToDefaultPrinter("MJM 80mm * Receipt Length", 80.1f, 4003.9f);
      }

      public static void AddMjm104MmPaperSizeToDefaultPrinter()
      {
         AddCustomPaperSizeToDefaultPrinter("MJM 104mm * Receipt Length", 104.1f, 4003.9f);
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// Adds the printer form to the default printer
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="paperName">Name of the printer form</param>
      /// <param name="widthMm">Width given in millimeters</param>
      /// <param name="heightMm">Height given in millimeters</param>
      public static void AddCustomPaperSizeToDefaultPrinter(string paperName, float widthMm, float heightMm)
      {
         PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
         string sPrinterName = pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName;
         AddCustomPaperSize(sPrinterName, paperName, widthMm, heightMm);
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// Add the printer form to a printer 
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="printerName">The printer name</param>
      /// <param name="paperName">Name of the printer form</param>
      /// <param name="widthMm">Width given in millimeters</param>
      /// <param name="heightMm">Height given in millimeters</param>
    public static void AddCustomPaperSize(string printerName, string paperName, float
      widthMm, float heightMm)
    {
      if (PlatformID.Win32NT == Environment.OSVersion.Platform)
      {
        // The code to add a custom paper size is different for Windows NT then it is
        // for previous versions of windows

        const int PRINTER_ACCESS_USE = 0x00000008;
        const int PRINTER_ACCESS_ADMINISTER = 0x00000004;
        const int FORM_PRINTER =   0x00000002;
      
        structPrinterDefaults defaults = new structPrinterDefaults();
        defaults.pDatatype = null;
        defaults.pDevMode = IntPtr.Zero;
        defaults.DesiredAccess = PRINTER_ACCESS_ADMINISTER | PRINTER_ACCESS_USE;

        IntPtr hPrinter = IntPtr.Zero;

        // Open the printer.
        if (OpenPrinter(printerName, out hPrinter, ref defaults))
        {
          try
          {
                  // delete the form incase it already exists
            DeleteForm(hPrinter, paperName);
                  // create and initialize the FORM_INFO_1 structure
            FormInfo1 formInfo = new FormInfo1();
            formInfo.Flags = 0;
            formInfo.pName = paperName;
                  // all sizes in 1000ths of millimeters
            formInfo.Size.width = (int)(widthMm * 1000.0); 
            formInfo.Size.height = (int)(heightMm * 1000.0);
            formInfo.ImageableArea.left = 0;
            formInfo.ImageableArea.right = formInfo.Size.width;
            formInfo.ImageableArea.top = 0;
            formInfo.ImageableArea.bottom = formInfo.Size.height;
            if (!AddForm(hPrinter, 1, ref formInfo))
            {
              StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
              strBuilder.AppendFormat("Failed to add the custom paper size {0} to the printer {1}, System error number: {2}",
                paperName, printerName, GetLastError());
              throw new ApplicationException(strBuilder.ToString());
            }

                  // INIT
                  const int DM_OUT_BUFFER = 2;
                  const int DM_IN_BUFFER = 8;
                  structDevMode devMode = new structDevMode();
                  IntPtr hPrinterInfo, hDummy;
                  PRINTER_INFO_9 printerInfo;
                  printerInfo.pDevMode = IntPtr.Zero;
                  int iPrinterInfoSize, iDummyInt;


                  // GET THE SIZE OF THE DEV_MODE BUFFER
                  int iDevModeSize = DocumentProperties(IntPtr.Zero, hPrinter, printerName, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, 0);

                  if(iDevModeSize < 0)
                     throw new ApplicationException("Cannot get the size of the DEVMODE structure.");

                  // ALLOCATE THE BUFFER
                  IntPtr hDevMode = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(iDevModeSize + 100);

                  // GET A POINTER TO THE DEV_MODE BUFFER 
                  int iRet = DocumentProperties(IntPtr.Zero, hPrinter, printerName, hDevMode, IntPtr.Zero, DM_OUT_BUFFER);

                  if(iRet < 0)
                     throw new ApplicationException("Cannot get the DEVMODE structure.");

                  // FILL THE DEV_MODE STRUCTURE
                  devMode = (structDevMode)Marshal.PtrToStructure(hDevMode, devMode.GetType());

                  // SET THE FORM NAME FIELDS TO INDICATE THAT THIS FIELD WILL BE MODIFIED
                  devMode.dmFields = 0x10000; // DM_FORMNAME 
                  // SET THE FORM NAME
                  devMode.dmFormName = paperName; 

                  // PUT THE DEV_MODE STRUCTURE BACK INTO THE POINTER
                  Marshal.StructureToPtr(devMode, hDevMode, true);

                  // MERGE THE NEW CHAGES WITH THE OLD
                  iRet = DocumentProperties(IntPtr.Zero, hPrinter, printerName, 
                           printerInfo.pDevMode, printerInfo.pDevMode, DM_IN_BUFFER | DM_OUT_BUFFER);

                  if(iRet < 0)
                     throw new ApplicationException("Unable to set the orientation setting for this printer.");

                  // GET THE PRINTER INFO SIZE
                  GetPrinter(hPrinter, 9, IntPtr.Zero, 0, out iPrinterInfoSize);
                  if(iPrinterInfoSize == 0)
                     throw new ApplicationException("GetPrinter failed. Couldn't get the # bytes needed for shared PRINTER_INFO_9 structure");

                  // ALLOCATE THE BUFFER
                  hPrinterInfo = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(iPrinterInfoSize + 100);

                  // GET A POINTER TO THE PRINTER INFO BUFFER
                  bool bSuccess = GetPrinter(hPrinter, 9, hPrinterInfo, iPrinterInfoSize, out iDummyInt);

                  if(!bSuccess)
                     throw new ApplicationException("GetPrinter failed. Couldn't get the shared PRINTER_INFO_9 structure");

                  // FILL THE PRINTER INFO STRUCTURE
                  printerInfo = (PRINTER_INFO_9)Marshal.PtrToStructure(hPrinterInfo, printerInfo.GetType());
                  printerInfo.pDevMode = hDevMode;

                  // GET A POINTER TO THE PRINTER INFO STRUCTURE
                  Marshal.StructureToPtr(printerInfo, hPrinterInfo, true);

                  // SET THE PRINTER SETTINGS
                  bSuccess = SetPrinter(hPrinter, 9, hPrinterInfo, 0);

                  if(!bSuccess)
                     throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(), "SetPrinter() failed.  Couldn't set the printer settings");

                  // Tell all open programs that this change occurred.
                  SendMessageTimeout(
                     new IntPtr(HWND_BROADCAST), 
                     WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 
                     IntPtr.Zero, 
                     IntPtr.Zero, 
                     MJMCustomPrintForm.SendMessageTimeoutFlags.SMTO_NORMAL, 
                     1000, 
                     out hDummy);
          }
          finally
          {
            ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
          }
        }
        else
        {
          StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
          strBuilder.AppendFormat("Failed to open the {0} printer, System error number: {1}",
            printerName, GetLastError());
          throw new ApplicationException(strBuilder.ToString());
        }
      }
      else
      {
        structDevMode pDevMode = new structDevMode();
        IntPtr hDC = CreateDC(null, printerName, null, ref pDevMode);
        if (hDC != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
          const long DM_PAPERSIZE = 0x00000002L;
          const long DM_PAPERLENGTH = 0x00000004L;
          const long DM_PAPERWIDTH = 0x00000008L;
          pDevMode.dmFields = (int)(DM_PAPERSIZE | DM_PAPERWIDTH | DM_PAPERLENGTH);
          pDevMode.dmPaperSize = 256;
          pDevMode.dmPaperWidth = (short)(widthMm * 1000.0);
          pDevMode.dmPaperLength = (short)(heightMm * 1000.0);
          ResetDC(hDC, ref pDevMode);
          DeleteDC(hDC);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello Dmitry, your solution worked for me. Do you mind explaining why you had to change that part of the code? It's way over my head.